# Append a word to title of Google Calendar event using javascript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I maintain a google calendar for 4 branches. 
I've currently got a little bookmarklet (actually 4) that let's me put in the precise address with a simple click. However I'd like to add to the functionality so that when I click the button it adds the name of the branch to the end of the title in addition to pasting in the appropriate address. I'd like to add code to this so when I click it, `(Headquarters)` is appended to the end of the title.

```
javascript:var a=document.getElementsByClassName('textinput')[1];a.value='Headquarters Branch, Street, County, State, 12345';var e=document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");e.initEvent('change',true,true);a.dispatchEvent(e);void(0);
```

Bonus: By default the calendar selector is set to headquarters. If I could also change that to the appropriate branch when I click one of the others that would be fantastic!

Comment: Did you resolve this question? Are you still using bookmarklets to add events to google calendar? Have you changes to the new google calendar layout which appeared  in October do your bookmarklets still work?